# how to find slashes in a XML file with regex?

Tags: regex

I've to parse a xml-like file and replace the `/` with `_`.

But now my problem is I can't find the string `/` without finding the `</`.

Can anyone help me?

example String:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<database>
  <tables>
    <table>
      <name>users</name>
      <value>test/djha</value>
    </table>
  </tables>
</database>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex: `(?<!<)/`

It uses zero-width [*"negative lookbehind"*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Matches at a position if the pattern inside the lookahead cannot be matched ending at that position.

In XML you should also be aware of empty tags like `<table name="products" />`. So you are safer with something like this:

```
(?<!<)/(?!>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like so: `[^<]/`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[^<]/` to find the Slash. `[^<]` will stand for "anything but <".